# Accessing sequentially numbered controls in C# code behind

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms, dopostback

This issues is causing me no end of troubles! The requirements is for a web form (written in C#/ASP.Net Webforms) where the user can add and delete rows of controls for adding multiple instances of the same type pf data.

This page exists with in a larger site that has a hierarchy of MasterPages so I may be running into difficulty with MasterPages...

My issue is specifically with deleting a row from this "table". For good or for ill I built this as a Panel the holds multiple sub Panels. Each sub Panel represents one row of my "table".

My addRow buttons work perfectly. But the deleteRow buttons fail in different ways depending on how I try to handle them.

- If I register an EventHandler for the delete button the event fires and the row is deleted in memory but remains on the page until another button is clicked (causing a second PostBack event).
- If I use the JavaScript __doPostBack approach, I can access the event in my Page_Load method but I cannot get a object reference to the row I want to delete!

Here is my default.aspx (trimmed to the relevant parts):

```
<%@ Page Title="Alumni Outreach" Language="C#" EnableViewState="true" MasterPageFile="~/components/navigation/sidebar.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="default.aspx.cs" Inherits="www.law.unc.edu.alumni.outreach.outreach2" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/components/navigation/sidebar.master"%>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphContent1" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlInformation" runat="server">
        <h1>Community Outreach
        </h1>
        <p>
            <span class="carolinaBlue">Purpose:</span> To quantify the UNC School of Law's <span class="carolinaBlue">Legacy of Leadership
            </span>via Carolina Law alumni's stories of service, volunteerism, and leadership across the state and nation. Information gathered will be utilized in a variety of Carolina Law communnications/marketing pieces (for instance, an online presence with interactive maps) designed to illustrate Carolina Law alumni's leadership in the communities where they live and work.
        </p>
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlForm" runat="server">


        <h2>Volunteer Leadership Roles</h2>
        <p>
            Please share your commitment to community leadership by noting all organizations you have voluntarily served below.
        </p>
        <div style="display: inline-block;">
            <asp:Button ID="btnAddLeadershipRow" OnClick="BtnAddLeadershipRow_Click" Text="+" runat="server" />
        </div>
        <div style="display: inline-block">
            <div style="display: inline-block; width: 6.5em; font: 700 1em Verdana,Arial,Sans-Serif !important">Region</div>
            <div style="display: inline-block; width: 7em; font: 700 1em Verdana,Arial,Sans-Serif !important">Profit?</div>
            <div style="display: inline-block; width: 20.5em; font: 700 1em Verdana,Arial,Sans-Serif !important">Organization</div>
            <div style="display: inline-block; width: 14em; font: 700 1em Verdana,Arial,Sans-Serif !important">Position</div>
        </div>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlLeadershipFields" runat="server">
            <!-- dynamically add controls here -->
        </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

And here are the relevant parts of my default.aspx.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using BusinessLogic.Alumni.Outreach;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace www.law.unc.edu.alumni.outreach
{
    [ViewStateModeById]
    public partial class outreach2 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private List<String> regions;
        private List<String> profit;
        private List<Button> _foundControls = new List<Button>();

        public outreach2()
        {
            regions = new List<string> {
                "Local",
                "State",
                "National"
            };

            profit = new List<string> {
                "Non-Profit",
                "For-Profit"
            };
        }

        protected int LeadershipControlsMaxIndex
        {
            get {
                if (ViewState["LeadershipControlsMaxIndex"] == null)
                    ViewState.Add("LeadershipControlsMaxIndex", 0);
                return (int)ViewState["LeadershipControlsMaxIndex"];
            }
            set {
                if (ViewState["LeadershipControlsMaxIndex"] == null)
                    ViewState.Add("LeadershipControlsMaxIndex", value);
                else
                    ViewState["LeadershipControlsMaxIndex"] = value;
            }
        }

        protected List<int> LeadershipControlsIndexes
        {
            get { 
                if (!(ViewState["LeadershipControlsIndexes"] is List<int>))
                {
                    ViewState["LeadershipControlsIndexes"] = new List<int>();
                }
                return (List<int>)ViewState["LeadershipControlsIndexes"];
            }
            set { ViewState["LeadershipControlsIndexes"] = value; }
        }

        // If this is the first time the user is visiting the page 
        //  create one set of controls
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                CreateLeadershipControl();
            }
            else if (Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                // if I do:
                // btnDelete.OnClientClick = "javascript:__doPostBack(\""+btnDelete.ID+"\",\"\")";
                // when creating the delete button I enter the following if
                // clause but cannot get an object (or Control or Button)
                // reference to the btnDelete, whether I use this.Form or
                // pnlLeadershipFields in the call to FindChildControlsRecursive
                if (Request["__EVENTTARGET"].Contains("btnLeadershipRowDelete"))
                {
                    FindChildControlsRecursive(this.Form);
                    object btnDelete = _foundControls.Find(x => x.ID == Request["__EVENTTARGET"]);
                    DeleteControls(btnDelete);
                }
                RecreateLeadershipControls();
            }
        }

        public void FindChildControlsRecursive(Control control)
        {
            foreach (Control childControl in control.Controls)
            {
                if (childControl.GetType() == typeof(Button))
                {
                    _foundControls.Add((Button)childControl);
                }
                else
                {
                    FindChildControlsRecursive(childControl);
                }
            }
        }

        private void CreateLeadershipControl()
        {
            LeadershipControlsMaxIndex++;
            LeadershipControlsIndexes.Add(LeadershipControlsMaxIndex - 1);
            AddLeadershipControls(LeadershipControlsIndexes[LeadershipControlsIndexes.Count - 1]);
        }

        private void RecreateLeadershipControls()
        {
            List<int> indexes = LeadershipControlsIndexes;

            for (int i = 0; i < indexes.Count; i++)
            {
                AddLeadershipControls(indexes[i]);
            }
        }

        private void AddLeadershipControls(int index)
        {
            Panel pnlLeadershipControls = new Panel
            {
                ID = "LeadershipControls" + index.ToString(),
                CssClass = "pnlControls"
            };

            Button btnDelete = new Button()
            {
                ID = "btnLeadershipRowDelete" + index.ToString(),
                Text = "-"
            };
            //btnDelete.Click += new EventHandler(BtnDeleteRow_Click);
            btnDelete.OnClientClick = "javascript:__doPostBack(\""+btnDelete.ID+"\",\"\")";
            btnDelete.Attributes.Add("style", "display: inline-block; width: 1.4em;");
            pnlLeadershipControls.Controls.Add(btnDelete);

            DropDownList ddlRegion = new DropDownList
            {
                DataSource = regions,
                ID = "LeadershipRegion" + index.ToString()
            };
            ddlRegion.DataBind();
            ddlRegion.Attributes.Add("style", "display: inline-block; width: 7em;");
            pnlLeadershipControls.Controls.Add(ddlRegion);

            DropDownList ddlProfit = new DropDownList
            {
                DataSource = profit,
                ID = "LeadershipProfit" + index.ToString(),
                CssClass = "ddlProfit"
            };
            ddlProfit.DataBind();
            ddlProfit.Attributes.Add("style", "display: inline-block; width: 7.5em;");
            pnlLeadershipControls.Controls.Add(ddlProfit);

            TextBox txtOrg = new TextBox
            {
                ID = "txtLeadershipOrganization" + index.ToString()
            };
            txtOrg.Attributes.Add("style", "display: inline-block; width: 20em;");
            pnlLeadershipControls.Controls.Add(txtOrg);

            TextBox txtPos = new TextBox
            {
                ID = "txtLeadershipPosition" + index.ToString()
            };
            txtPos.Attributes.Add("style", "display: inline-block; width: 20em;");
            pnlLeadershipControls.Controls.Add(txtPos);

            CheckBox cbCurrent = new CheckBox
            {
                ID = "cbLeadershipCurrent" + index.ToString(),
                Text = "Current?",
            };
            cbCurrent.Attributes.Add("style", "display: inline-block; font: 700 1em Verdana,Arial,Sans-Serif !important");
            pnlLeadershipControls.Controls.Add(cbCurrent);

            pnlLeadershipFields.Controls.Add(pnlLeadershipControls);
        }


        private void DeleteControls(object sender)
        {
            Button button = (Button)sender;
            string id = button.ID;
            int index = Int32.Parse(Regex.Match(id, @"\d+$").Value);
            Panel row = (Panel)button.Parent;

            for (int i = row.Controls.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                if (row.Controls[i] is Button)
                    ((Button)row.Controls[i]).Click -= new EventHandler(BtnDeleteRow_Click);
                row.Controls[i].Dispose();
            }
            row.Parent.FindControl(row.ID).Dispose();
            if (id.Contains("Leadership"))
            {
                LeadershipControlsIndexes.RemoveAt(LeadershipControlsIndexes.FindIndex(x => x == index));
            }
        }

        protected void BtnAddLeadershipRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CreateLeadershipControl();
        }

        // If I do:
        // btnDelete.Click += new EventHandler(BtnDeleteRow_Click);
        // when creating the delete button, this method is called,
        // but too late in the page life cycle
        protected void BtnDeleteRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DeleteControls(sender);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to add the rendered HTML, but went over the character limit for a new post!

**In summary:**

I understand why 'BtnDeleteRow_Click()' handler is not working the way I want it to, so I switched to using '__doPostBack' in the hopes that I could catch the deletion event earlier in the Page Life Cycle. I can catch it in Page_load, which I believe is the sweet spot (my ViewState has been loaded so I have access to my row indexes, but the page has not been rendered). But since I cannot get any sort of object reference to the actual button that was clicked, I cannot move forward. When I get to Page_load, I do have the correct ID in 'Request["__EVENTTARGET"]'.

Comment: To the anonymous voter who down voted my question without even a comment - I spent most of yesterday researching my problem with no useful results, I have tried multiple approaches to solving it on my own and finally posted here in the hopes that someone would have a useful suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your goal, I would consider using a ListView wrapped in an UpdatePanel for this sort of functionality. The following example uses tables, but without them you can format the form anyway you would like:

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44070/Insert-a-new-record-using-ListView-with-a-GridView

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow! Could you include a little more detail from the linked page in your answer please? Link-only answers are generally discouraged as the linked page may be removed and the information lost.

Comment: Hi Ben, I think the code sample is a bit too lengthy for me to quote here?

Comment: My goal is to have a table-like appearance. one or two of the cells are drop downs, two are text edits and the last is a checkbox. The nested Panels I have used may not be pretty but they work and as I said above the delete buttons work (but you have to somehow refresh the page for the effect to be obvious). I'll have to read the post you referenced carefully because I've yet to work with UpdatePanels of ListViews.

Comment: OK, I use this method a lot so let me know if you run into any problems or have any questions.

Comment: I'll be reading the blog post tonight or tomorrow. I could not get to it today because Instagram killed my main page by killing off the REST endpoint we were using and I had to spend most of the day figuring out what had been done before me and creating an error check to trap Instagram's error message and fall back to a static image.

Comment: I've been pulled in to more fire fighting today so I have not tackled the linked blog post entirely yet but it does look promising.